# Create new NavigationViewItem with a ContentDialog and add to a database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, uwp, desktop

I create a web browser which use the NavigationView.

I want to add a custom Item who it can be stored in a database to avoid a reset when the user quit the application.

I tried a prototype in my code but doesn't affect the NavigationView.

Here is my code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<!-- WebBrowser -->
    <controls:WebView2 x:Name="webView2" x:FieldModifier="public"
                       Source="https://www.youtube.com"
                       Margin="40,0,0,40"
                       NavigationStarting="webView2_NavigationStarting"/>

    <!-- Navigation bars -->
    <CommandBar x:Name="commandBar"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                x:FieldModifier="public">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <Grid/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="backButton" x:FieldModifier="public" Visibility="Collapsed" Icon="Back" Label="Go Back" Click="backButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="forwardButton" x:FieldModifier="public" Visibility="Collapsed" Icon="Forward" Label="Go Forward" Click="forwardButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="refreshButton" x:FieldModifier="public" Visibility="Collapsed" Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh" Click="refreshButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Add a new Social Media" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Remove the current Social Media" Click="AppBarButton_Click_1"/>
    </CommandBar>
    <NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"
                    x:Name="navView"
                    PaneTitle="WebSM"
                    SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged"
                    IsPaneOpen="False"
                    x:FieldModifier="public">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="YouTube" x:Name="YouTube" Icon="Globe" Tag="YouTube"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Twitch" x:Name="Twitch" Icon="Globe" Tag="Twitch"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Discord" x:Name="Discord" Icon="Globe" Tag="Discord"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Twitter" x:Name="Twitter" Icon="Globe" Tag="Twitter"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Reddit" x:Name="Reddit" Icon="Globe" Tag="Reddit"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Spotify" x:Name="Spotify" Icon="Globe" Tag="Spotify"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private void NavigationView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSettingsSelected)
        {
            settingsView.IsPaneOpen = true;
            navView.SelectedItem = null;
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationViewItem Item = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;

            switch (Item.Tag)
            {
                case "YouTube":
                    webView2.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com");
                    break;
                case "Twitch":
                    webView2.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.twitch.tv");
                    break;
                case "Discord":
                    webView2.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://discord.com/channels/@me");
                    break;
                case "Twitter":
                    webView2.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://twitter.com/home");
                    break;
                case "Reddit":
                    webView2.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.reddit.com");
                    break;
                case "Spotify":
                    webView2.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://open.spotify.com");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

**NewShortcut.xaml**

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="WebSM.NewShortcut"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WebSM"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="Add a new shortcut"
PrimaryButtonText="Add"
SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"
PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick"
Height="Auto" Width="Auto">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Name of the shortcut:"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="URL of the website:"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox2"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="Automaticaly open when it's added"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**NewShortcut.xaml.cs**

```
private async void ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            this.Hide();
            ContentDialog errorNoShortcut = new ErrorNoShortcut();
            await errorNoShortcut.ShowAsync();
        }
        else if (textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            this.Hide();
            ContentDialog errorNoURL = new ErrorNoURL();
            await errorNoURL.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
            DataAccess.AddData(textBox1.Text);
            DataAccess.AddData(textBox2.Text);
            mainPage.navView.MenuItemsSource = DataAccess.GetData();
        }
```

**DataAccess.cs**

```
public class DataAccess
{
    public async static void InitializeDatabase()
    {
        await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("WebSMDataBase.db", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        string dbpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "WebSMDataBase.db");
        using (SqliteConnection db =
           new SqliteConnection($"Filename={dbpath}"))
        {
            db.Open();

            String tableCommand = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT " +
                "EXISTS Shortcut (Primary_Key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "Text_Entry NVARCHAR(2048) NULL)";

            SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);

            createTable.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }

    public static void AddData(string inputText)
    {
        string dbpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "WebSMDataBase.db");
        using (SqliteConnection db =
          new SqliteConnection($"Filename={dbpath}"))
        {
            db.Open();

            SqliteCommand insertCommand = new SqliteCommand();
            insertCommand.Connection = db;

            // Use parameterized query to prevent SQL injection attacks
            insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Shortcut VALUES (NULL, @Entry);";
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entry", inputText);

            insertCommand.ExecuteReader();

            db.Close();
        }
    }

    public static List<String> GetData()
    {
        List<String> entries = new List<string>();

        string dbpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "WebSMDataBase.db");
        using (SqliteConnection db =
           new SqliteConnection($"Filename={dbpath}"))
        {
            db.Open();

            SqliteCommand selectCommand = new SqliteCommand
                ("SELECT Text_Entry from Shortcut", db);

            SqliteDataReader query = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (query.Read())
            {
                entries.Add(query.GetString(0));
            }

            db.Close();
        }

        return entries;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added .xaml files

Comment: Any updates for this thead ?

Comment: Hello, sorry for not responding, I am on holiday. I let you know for any updates.

Comment: Does the following answer work ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `MenuItemsSource` is string list, but you have not use MenuItemTemplate for you NavigationView, if you set MenuItemsSource as string list directly, it will only render string content.

For this scenario, you need to update NavigationView like this.

```
<NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="{Binding}" Icon="Globe" />
    </DataTemplate>
</NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
```

And udpate your switch  condition in the  `NavigationView_SelectionChanged` event

```
switch (args.SelectedItem)
        {
            case "YouTube":
              
                break;
            case "Twitch":
               
                break;
            case "Discord":
              
                break;
            case "Twitter":
               
                break;
            case "Reddit":
             
                break;
            case "Spotify":
               
                break;
        }
```

**And please note** you could not access `NavigationView` with new mian page instance. Please make a static instance for current page like the following.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Current = this;
}
public static MainPage Current;
```

**Access navView with static field in the dialog**

```
MainPage.Current.navView.MenuItemsSource = DataAccess.GetData();
```